# How to use Django Rest API in Django normal project for autocomplete using Select2?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jquery-select2

In my Django project, I have a model named **Product**. The model consists of products which have following entities:

> name, id, price and so on.

In my project, an admin can add a new/old product anytime.

Now, for searching, I want to add autocomplete. I want to use [Select2](https://select2.org/).

So users don't have to memorize the name of the products. To do that I found out [here in the Select2 doc](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)
that :

> Select2 comes with AJAX support built in, using jQuery's AJAX methods

With this, I can search an API and fetch the data to show the users in autocomplete search field.

**My Question:**

- Should I create a **Django rest API** and use that API to store products and fetch the data?

  1.1 Would it be wise?

  1.2 Is it possible to make a rest API within a normal Django project? If not then how to do that?
- Or should I just use a normal `urls.py` and querying the result from
  `Select2 ajax function` to that `urls.py` and to a custom `query.py` and
  fetch the data directly from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using rest framework with normal Django project would cause any problem. You are just adding some extra urls, that's all. It won't cause any problem to your project. Moreover, you can use the API to get json data of various models.

Hope this helps.